# Merging multiple columns from different dataframes using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on lung cancer detection. It has been divided into left and right zone. Both of these data set has same columns names with different readings. I have normalized the data.The set of feature level has come down. Now i want to merge both of them. . How can i proceed? It might get overridden. I am not sure if i need to rename/prefix the same column names with left and right.if this is the correct way. I need some help on this.

Here is the sample data set

```
   Patient Id       Mean Radius          Mean texture
    190              17.99                   10.38
    198               19.56                   21.25
```

The same columns are repeated in both datasets with different readings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: This is a `pandas` question (tag added), and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Simply do an append operation:

```
df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=False)
```